# Access Report Printing Problem

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have shipped my Access App with the accde format. But when users open a report in preview mode, they cannot get the right-click menu to print it. The print function is accessible only with the Ctrl-P keystroke.

I tried with my accdb format, I can always call the menu by right click. But in accde, when i right click on the report, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced a similar issue when using the runtime version of Access. I worked around this by  setting the `Shortcut Menu Bar` property on the appropriate objects. You should be able to do the same in your report.

[Check out this blog post](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-access/archive/2009/05/21/how-to-create-a-shortcut-menu-for-a-form-form-control-or-report.aspx) for a bit of an overview of the process if you aren't familiar with it.

There is also a [nice page here on msdn.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff194247.aspx)